# Tracking one marker at a time vuforia

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia, hololens

I am creating a HoloLens application with Vuforia, and i have a total of 9 markers and associated GameObjects with each marker. I want my application to show only one object at a time: for example, I scan the first marker, show the first object; when i scan the second marker, i want the first object to disappear and only the second object to show, and so on.

I tried adding a script to each GameObject that would destroy the GameObjects in the scene, but that did not work.

I have very little knowledge with C# so please point me to specific code.

Thanks all!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Show at least what you have tried this far.

Comment: @pirho The question is actually asked correctly, this is about some design within Vuforia, no code is required to be shown.

Comment: @Everts Thank you for correcting me. It was this _I have very little knowledge with C# so please point me to specific code._ that made me suspect question lacks own effort. Also more detailed description what & how tried to do might have been in place.

Comment: Basically, I can't remember the exact terms so I'll put it as comment (someone will most likely find and post as answer). The Vuforia camera component has a setting for how many simultaneous target to track. I think Max is 5 but setting to 1 means once a target is found, the system does not look for another.

Comment: @Everts thank you for your input. true, the camera has the setting, but i also need to enable extended tracking: while the camera cannot track more than one marker, it will still show all the other objects (again, due to the extended tracking). Any way i can incorporate a code on detection that destroys everything in the scene?

Answer (score 0):

In order to control the maximum number of targets to be detected at the same time you need to use Vuforia's hint:

```
Vuforia::setHint(Vuforia::HINT_MAX_SIMULTANEOUS_IMAGE_TARGETS, <desired number>);
```

This is what you asked  - however, according to what you wrote in the comments this is not really what you need. If your want to use extended tracking for other targets, it means they have to be detected too. So, what you really need is - once you have a target, to know if it is extended right now or not, and act accordingly.
This is done via:

```
if ( result.getStatus() == Vuforia::TrackableResult::EXTENDED_TRACKED )
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an option in the Vuforia configuration.

1. Select your scene's ARCamera asset
2. Click "Open Vuforia Configuration"
3. Change "Max Simultaneous Tracked Images" to 1.

I saw that you mentioned this doesn't work with Extended Tracking.  I haven't noticed this behavior myself, but if needed you can manually toggle the active states of the objects with `GameObject.SetActive()`.